# How to upload data in power apps table using python

Tags: python, post, python-requests, odata, powerapps

I've a requirement to insert new data in a table.

I tried below code:

```
product_record_id="7ec1fc08-fcdb-ee11-904d-00224803f3ee"
LookupTo="LookupTableName"
#Update table code
# Define the data to be posted
 data_to_post = [
                        {
                        "id": product_id,
                        "Product_value@odata.bind": f"/{LookupTo}({product_record_id})"
                        }
                        # Add more dictionaries for additional records if needed
                        ]

   # Make the POST request
   response = requests.post(post_url, json=data_to_post, headers=headers)

  # Check if the request was successful
   if response.status_code == 201:  # 201 indicates success for POST request
        print("Data successfully posted.")
   else:
        print("Error:", response.status_code)
        print("Response:", response.text)
```

After getting response from postman i get below values for lookup table and i've made changes regarding that as shown above:

```
"value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"992\"",
            "_owningbusinessunit_value": "",
            "id": "7ec1fc08-fcdb-ee11-904d-00224803f3ee",
            "statecode": 0,
            "statuscode": 1,
            "entityname": "Product",
            
        }
```

But above python code is throwing below error:

> InnerException : Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A property
> 'Product_value' which only has property annotations in the payload but
> no property value is declared to be of type 'Edm.Guid'. In OData, only
> navigation properties and named streams can be represented as
> properties without values.\r\n   at
> Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadPropertyWithoutValue(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState
> resourceState, String propertyName)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(PropertyParsingResult
> propertyParsingResult, String propertyName)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector
> propertyAndAnnotationCollector, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue, Action`2 handleProperty)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadResourceContent(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState
> resourceState)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.StartReadingResource()\r\n
> at
> Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadResourceSetItemStart(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector
> propertyAndAnnotationCollector, SelectedPropertiesNode
> selectedProperties)\r\n

As I'm new to this any help will be thankful.